# Update selected rows in sqlite table in r

Tags: r, sqlite, r-dbi

I am using the `RSQLite` package in a shiny app. I need to be able to dynamically update an sqlite db as users progress through the app. I want to use the `UPDATE` syntax in SQLite to achieve this, but I have come up against a problem when trying to update multiple rows for the same user.

Consider the following code:

```
# Load libraries
library("RSQLite")

## Path for SQLite db
sqlitePath <- "test.db"

# Create db to store tables
con <- dbConnect(SQLite(),sqlitePath)

## Create toy data
who <- c("jane", "patrick", "samantha", "jane", "patrick", "samantha")
tmp_var_1 <- c(1,2,3, 4, 5, 6)
tmp_var_2 <- c(2,4,6,8,10,12)

# Create original table
users <- data.frame(who = as.character(who), tmp_var_1 = tmp_var_1, tmp_var_2 = tmp_var_2)
users$who <- as.character(users$who)

# Write original table
dbWriteTable(con, "users", users)

# Subset users data
jane <- users[who=="jane",]
patrick <- users[who=="patrick",]
samantha <- users[who=="samantha",]

# Edit Jane's data
jane$tmp_var_1 <- c(99,100)

# Save edits back to SQL (this is where the problem is!)
table <- "users"

db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), sqlitePath)
query <- sprintf(
  "UPDATE %s SET %s = ('%s') WHERE who = %s",
  table, 
  paste(names(jane), collapse = ", "),
  paste(jane, collapse = "', '"),
  "'jane'"
)
dbGetQuery(db, query)

## Load data to check update has worked
loadData <- function(table) {
  # Connect to the database
  db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), sqlitePath)
  # Construct the fetching query
  query <- sprintf("SELECT * FROM %s", table)
  # Submit the fetch query and disconnect
  data <- dbGetQuery(db, query)
  dbDisconnect(db)
  data
}

loadData("users")
```

Here I am trying to update the entry for `Jane` so that the values for `tmp_var_1` are changed, but all other columns remain the same. In response to questions from @zx8754 and @Altons posted below, the value for `query` is as follows:

```
UPDATE users SET who, tmp_var_1, tmp_var_2 = ('c(\"jane\", \"jane\")', 'c(99, 100)', 'c(2, 8)') WHERE who = 'jane'
```

The problem is almost certainly coming from the way that I am specifying the query to RSQlite. When I run `dbGetQuery(db, query)` I get the following error:

```
Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) : 
  error in statement: near ",": syntax error
```

Any suggestions for improvement would be most welcome.

Comment: If you check output of `sprintf()` you will see the problem.

Comment: can you print `query`? if you're updating multiple columns you may be missing a comma.

Comment: I've made some changes to the question to try and make things a little clearer. I've also included the print of ``query`` - I'm afraid I am new to SQLite and so am very possible making some very rudimentary errors.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to update two rows with two values, this is not how `UPDATE` works in SQL.